# Merge collections of different models and keep only unique models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Imagine there are two collections: `$companies` which is a collection of companies and `$contacts` which is collection of contacts. How can I merge them together and don't loose any data?

When I tried to use `merge()` method I loose some of my models because it seems like they're overwritten by keys. Keys are just numbers but since I separately get companies and contacts I have something like: `0,1,2,3` keys for companies and then again `0,1,2,3` for contacts so there is a conflict.

I haven't found any "append" method or something like that

**Update**

I'll describe in detail what I have. I have a `phone` model which represents a table which holds unique phone numbers for a user. 
Company has 2 foreign keys - `work_phone_id` and `mobile_phone_id` which are linked to phones table. Same for contacts. Both companies and contacts have 2 relationship based on the work_phone_id and contact_phone_id.

So, a `company` has 2 relationships:

```
/**
 * Company has a work phone.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function workPhone()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\EloquentModels\Phone', 'work_phone_id');
}

/**
 * Company has a mobile phone.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function mobilePhone()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\EloquentModels\Phone', 'mobile_phone_id');
}
```

And the same for contacts.

I need to get all related entities for a specific phone and loop through them. While looping I also need to access to company/contact relationships. So the result will be something like:

```
$companiesAndContacts = $this->phone->getRelatedCompaniesAndContacts($phoneId);

foreach ($companiesAndContacts as $entity) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Are Companies and Contracts related on database level? If so, why not just make a join and get all data with no risk of losing any of it?

Comment: Well I'll also need to use relationships on these models, if I do sql query I'll get an array result?

Comment: You can get an array if you want to. Laravel provides methods for that. In general though, you'll get some type of object depending on your query. Knowing Eloquent and Query Builder is crucial here.

Comment: But how I'll eventually get companies and contacts models merged together? I've managed to get companies (return Company::join...), and contacts (Contact::join...), but again I need them combined together. Get two collections combined together, because later I'll need to loop through them

Comment: Do the models share a foreign key - primary key pair?

Comment: I've added an update with description of my models. Thanks